# for loop only 3 times with itertools cycle

Tags: python, loops

Python beginner here seeking some guidance from the dev gods. I just want to repeat the for loop 3 (or x) times before breaking but I am still stuck in an infinite loops. Any suggestions?

```
for url in itertools.cycle(url_list):
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(6)
    cycle + 1
    if check_add_cart():
        print('In-Stock =) / ' + browser.title + ' / ' + now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif not check_add_cart():
        print('Out-of-Stock =( / ' + browser.title + ' / ' + now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    elif cycle == 3:
        break
        browser.close()
    else:
        print('Error')
```

Comment: Try correcting `cycle +1` to `cycle += 1`

Comment: Please check your code, it isn't indent.

Comment: Do you mean you want to cycle the list 3 times, or just 3 iterations?

Comment: @Cyttorak Just 3 iterations and I did update `cycle += 1`  but still will not stop the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `itertools`.

```
url_list = ['url_0', 'url_1', 'url_2']
x = 3

for i in range(x):
    print(f'Round {i}:')
    for url in url_list:
        print(f'  url: {url!r}')
```

Output:

```
Round 0:
  url: 'url_0'
  url: 'url_1'
  url: 'url_2'
Round 1:
  url: 'url_0'
  url: 'url_1'
  url: 'url_2'
Round 2:
  url: 'url_0'
  url: 'url_1'
  url: 'url_2'
```

Comment: thank you! this is what I was looking for, once the rounds have been completed where could I put `browser.close()` to close out the chrome session?

Comment: Just put it beyond the end of of the outermost `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
for i in range(3) # The code will happen 3 times
    # Do Stuff
```

Comment: how would I add the range within `for url in itertools.cycle(url_list):`

Comment: do this - `for url in url_list:`

Comment: that would work if you have a url_list and you don't need to use itertools if you just want to repeat it 3 times

Comment: However, if you want URL for more complex things than just repeating 3 times, I would edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you aren't changing the cycle variable.

```
cycle + 1
```

doesn't add 1 to cycle, but instead is the expression that is cycle+1.
try isntead

```
cycle += 1
```

also,

```
elif cycle == 3:
    break
    browser.close()
```

wont close the browser, as there is a break statement before it, changing their order should fix that.
The fix to the problem in the comments is turning the

```
elif cycle == 3:
    break
    browser.close()
```

into a

```
if cycle == 3:
    break
    browser.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated based on suggestion but the loop still will not stop